# Optimised approach for matching tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a predefined table in my database. Table1(a,b,c,d,e) and a Table2(e,f). A new Table3(a,b,c,d,e,f) needs to be created where f is the field where Table1.e=Table2.e. The entries in Table1 will be added at very high rate 2000,1000 entries per minute. Number of entries in Table2 won't change.

Table3 needs to have data for a real time system. What would be best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Why do you need a table3? A very simple query will get you the data from the two existing tables

Comment: it's very difficult to give an opinion without knowing the schema, environment, etc, but one of many things you can consider is a view on table1/table2

Comment: 2000 inserts per minute is a 'modest' rate.  Leave the tables normalized.